# ANR for HTC 10, ExifInterface

Tags: android, crash

I get following error message on play store with HTC 10 (htc_pmeuhljapan), Android 7.0.

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 25. Wait queue head age: 15678.7ms.)

According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html), I understand that which is ANR. But I am not able to reproduce this.

Code is as below:

```
 private void refreshListCameraRoll()
    {
        String[] projection;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cur;                         
        projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED
        };

        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;               
        cur = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"      
        );   
        Log.i("ListingImages", " query count=" + cur.getCount());
        showProgress("Loading...");

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            Long id;
            String path;
            long dateS;

            int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int pathColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            int dateSColumn = 
            cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);

            do {                   
                id = cur.getLong(idColumn);
                path = cur.getString(pathColumn);
                dateS = cur.getLong(dateSColumn);                   
                long dateMS = dateS / S_IN_A_DAY * MS_IN_A_DAY;
                long differenceDates = 0;
                try {                           
                       Date currentDate = new Date();
                       Date oldDate = new Date(dateMS);                          
                       long difference = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime());
                       differenceDates = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(differenceDates <= 31) {
                    ExifInterface intf = null;
                    try {
                        intf = new ExifInterface(path);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (intf != null) {
                        String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
                        if (dateString != null) {
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
                            try {
                                   Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
                                   dateMS = date.getTime() + MS_IN_A_DAY;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putBoolean(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_ISVIDEO, false);
                    bundle.putLong(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_ID, id);
                    bundle.putString(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_PATH, path);
                    bundle.putLong(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_DATE, dateMS);
                    mListMedia.add(bundle);
                }
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        cur.close();                     
        projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED
        };


        uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;        
        cur = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"        // Ordering
        );

        Log.i("ListingVideos", " query count=" + cur.getCount());

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            Long id;
            String path;
            long dateS;

            int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            int pathColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            int dateSColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED);

            do {
                // Get the field values
                id = cur.getLong(idColumn);
                path = cur.getString(pathColumn);
                dateS = cur.getInt(dateSColumn);

                //filter media files for ONE month
                long dateMS = dateS / S_IN_A_DAY * MS_IN_A_DAY;
                long differenceDates = 0;
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    Date date = new Date(dateMS);
                    //Comparing dates
                    long difference = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - date.getTime());
                    differenceDates = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(differenceDates <= 31) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putBoolean(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_ISVIDEO, true);
                    bundle.putLong(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_ID, id);
                    bundle.putString(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_PATH, path);
                    bundle.putLong(MEDIA_BUNDLE_KEY_DATE, dateS * MS_IN_A_S);
                    mListMedia.add(bundle);

                }
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

        hideProgress();
    }
```

As [android developer document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)), ExifInterface added in API level 24, so it won't be problem with HTC 10, android 7.0.

Below is play store trace: EDIT:

```
     "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x73eccab0 self=0xebc33400
   | sysTid=12463 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xebcf6534
   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=765 stm=278 core=0 HZ=100
   | stack=0xff197000-0xff199000 stackSize=8MB
   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
   at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read (ByteArrayInputStream.java)
   at android.media.ExifInterface$ByteOrderAwarenessDataInputStream.readInt (ExifInterface.java:2636)
   at android.media.ExifInterface$ByteOrderAwarenessDataInputStream.readUnsignedInt (ExifInterface.java:2677)
   at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory (ExifInterface.java:2212)
   at android.media.ExifInterface.readImageFileDirectory (ExifInterface.java:2262)
   at android.media.ExifInterface.readExifSegment (ExifInterface.java:2093)
   at android.media.ExifInterface.getJpegAttributes (ExifInterface.java:1892)
   at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes (ExifInterface.java:1474)
   at android.media.ExifInterface.<init> (ExifInterface.java:1111)
   at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.AlbumFragment.refreshListCameraRoll (AlbumFragment.java:815)
   at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.AlbumFragment.refreshList (AlbumFragment.java:603)
   at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.AlbumFragment.setAlbum (AlbumFragment.java:575)
   at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.AlbumFragment.access$000 (AlbumFragment.java:103)
   at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.AlbumFragment$1.onTabSelected (AlbumFragment.java:264)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab (TabLayout.java:1025)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab (TabLayout.java:995)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select (TabLayout.java:1272)
   at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick (TabLayout.java:1377)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22396)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:173)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6459)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:938)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

It's sure that Line 815 on AlbumFragment.java, which is

```
intf = new ExifInterface(path);
```

And it's crashing app. Any idea on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html)

Comment: ExifInterface that you are using was added way back in api level 5. Although you are using exif interace to just fetch the datetime and also fetching date time from cursor. So why not directly use from cursor and remove exif interface

Comment: @Vivek Mishra, I did what you suggested and it seems reasonable. Even tho I haven't found the source of problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

**ANR**

> In any situation in which your app performs a potentially lengthy
>   operation, you should not perform the work on the UI thread, but
>   instead create a worker thread and do most of the work there. This
>   keeps the UI thread (which drives the user interface event loop)
>   running and prevents the system from concluding that your code has
>   frozen. Because such threading usually is accomplished at the class
>   level, you can think of responsiveness as a class problem. (Compare
>   this with basic code performance, which is a method-level concern.)

[For more info](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

So if i trying to do observe you code, your doing a lot of work in UI thread which is main reason of throwing ANR. So you need to put your code into [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
private class RefreshListCameraRollAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        refreshListCameraRoll();
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // do ur UI work here and hide loader
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         // show your loader here if you want to show
    }


}
```